Disable Computer Objects & Move to Disable O/U Script Stopped Working
Good morning, all:
I have a PowerShell script that was working for a few years, and now when I went to check it this morning, it fails and I just can't figure out why.
UPDATED TO ORIGINAL CODE THAT USED TO WORK
Here is my script:
#$Today = Get-Date -Format d
#$Time = Get-Date -Format t

$CurrentDate = (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$cutoff = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)
Get-ADComputer -Filter { LastLogonDate -lt $cutoff -and enabled -eq $true } -Properties lastlogondate |

foreach-object {
    $Today = Get-Date -Format d
    $Time = Get-Date -Format t
    $Destination = "OU=Computers,OU=Disabled Objects,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"
    $SourceOU = $_.Distinguishedname
    $Description = "Disabled on $Today at $Time - Source OU was $SourceOU"
    Set-ADComputer $_.distinguishedname -Description $Description -Enabled $false
    Move-ADObject $_.distinguishedname -TargetPath $Destination 
    Write-host "Moved $($_.distinguishedname) to $Destination"
}

Now when I run the script, it simply just goes back to a PowerShell Command Prompt with no output or A/D changes made at all. I know I have 27 objects that should be moved.
Only thing that was done, was this script used to run on a Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller. Since, that server underwent an In-Place Upgrade to Server 2019.
Thanks for all help in advance.

Is Export-CSV [...] on the end of that line new? It's preventing the Get-ADComputer output from going to foreach-object. The rest of the commands are failing because their input is just null

@Cpt.Whale - You were correct, sir. I just added a pipe to the end of that line, and now I don't get any error at all, I can see the A/D Module load (the yellow progress line that you see when a module loads), then it just goes back to a Powershell Prompt. I also made this change: Set-ADComputer -Identity $_.distinguishedname -Description $Description -Enabled $false to see if it would make a difference or not from the original error, and it did not.

@Cpt.Whale - Looks like someone added the export-csv trying to modify my script. I updated the post with current and correct information.

But now you also edited away the error message on Set-ADComputer.. Does that mean you receive no errors at all anymore? Is the OU path in $Destination still correct after the server update? -Filter should actually be a string, not a scriptblock

What happens if you run just down to the Get-ADComputer line on that server (just to make sure that it returns the computer objects you expect)? Typos, replication issues, or the computer objects already being disabled could all result in the same behavior
